# Python regex to match "spaced out" words

Tags: python, regex

When dealing with text files that have been produced using optical character recognition (OCR) I often come across lines or parts of lines

```
t h a t  a r e  s p a c e d  o u t  l i k e  t h i s.
```

I would like to be able to use a regular expression to match these words and smash the letters back together. But I have no idea how to do this using capture groups or my usual toolbox of regular expression knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is probably what you are looking for:

```
re.sub(r' (.)', r'\1', txt)
```

Comment: if the file contains  some other lines like `foo bar`, Your regex turns this into `foobar`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You are right, but here the string is supposed to have an additional space before each character *(except the first)*. you have no chance to find something like `foo bar`, but rather something like `f o o  b a r`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=\s\s|^)((?:\w\s|\w\.)+)
```

This will work.

[See Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pN9aG5/4)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
re.sub(r' \b', r'', txt)
```